# How to intercept submit of form in Elementor popup

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, popup, elementor

I have created a popup that will be used as a login form + integration with third-party services (not important for the case). I want to intercept the form submission and send the username and password to a custom API to perform authentication and return a session token. How do we achieve this with JS?

I tried the following:

```
$ = jQuery

$( document ).on( 'elementor/popup/show', ( event, id, instance ) => {
    const formElement = document.getElementById("login-form");
    formElement.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log(formElement)
    } );
} );
```

But the console output shows the form data empty and the submission is done, rather than stopped in any way. I am new to Elementor and Wordpress so maybe it is something really stupid.

I was expecting the submission to be blocked and the console log to output the username and password. How to use this form input to call a custom API? "Action after submission" option in the form I think will not work as I need to pass the form data in a specific format to the custom API.